Mesh looks black in Sculpt Mode
I've been following an online course to learn character sculpting in Blender (I'm pretty new to this). However, I've encountered a problem while working on texture painting for my character. In Object mode, I can perfectly visualize my painting in any display mode (Solid, Material, or Rendered). But when I switch to Sculpting mode to make some changes while visualizing the colors, the entire mesh turns black in Rendered or Material display.
I've tried solutions such as deleting and recreating the material, as well as changing the Render Engine and device. I haven't found any answers online. Can anyone help?


UPDATE:
in cycles the mesh completely dissapears in sculpt mode+ render view. in eevee the mesh appears black.

Please add your images directly into the question. If you put links to them on external sites they will not be available to users reading your question in future. How to upload an image to a post.

Maybe you've masked the whole mesh? Try Alt M?

it didnt' work :( the mask is cleared

Maybe a bit late, but did you check if this is coming from a Vertex Color layer? They default to all black when created. You can check this in Vertex Paint Mode, and if it is the case, just use the color filler tool and fill it back to white.

Also change the display from attribute  to material or something else (inside the matcaps menu).
